# Casting a function parameter from void* to actual

Tags: c++

I have a routine that gets passed a void* to a structure.  In the
routine I cast it to the correct type, e.g.

```
SomeFunc(void* pMsg) {
  printf("Event = %d\n", static_cast<struct MyEventMsg*>(pMsg)->Event);
}
```

If I am accessing many members of the structure the code looks pretty
messy.  I can create a new pointer of the correct type and assign it
the cast void*, but it seems like it shouldn't be necessary to create
a temporary variable just for this purpose.  Is there some way to cast
the parameter pMsg to the correct type?

Thanks
Doug

Comment: Is there some reason you don't want to pass a pointer of the correct type?

Comment: What's the problem with what you have? You don't need to say `struct` in C++, if that helps. You can also typedef the pointer-to-struct somewhere.

Comment: I am confused. You don't want to cast for each access individually, but you also don't want to cast once and cache the result? What else are you looking for?

Comment: *beep* *beep* *beep* Type safety failure alert.

Answer (score 4):

Creating the pointer of the correct type and assigning it the cast of the void* is the correct way to go. It will make the code shorter and easier to read, if you choose a "good" name for the pointer.

You say that you think the pointer "unnecessary". If this is because you think that there is a run time cost associated with it, you may well find out that the compiler will eliminate the pointer for you.

Comment: +1 Same goes with using temporary non-pointer variables to make complex expressions easier to read.

Answer (score 2):

The way to do what you ask is

```
SomeFunc(void* pMsg) {
  MyEventMsg * pM = static_cast<struct MyEventMsg*>(pMsg);
  printf("Event = %d\n", pM->Event);
  printf("Something Else = %d\n", pM->SomeOtherMember);
  ...
}
```

But I would recommend something more C++:

```
SomeFunc(MyEventMsg &Msg) {  // consider making this const
  cout << "Event = " << Msg.Event << endl;
  cout << "Something Else = " << Msg.SomeOtherMember << endl;
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

No, as a matter of fact it should be. Static cast is your best option. Don't worry about the temporary. It will most likely be optimized away by your compiler

Answer (score 1):

Just go with the temporary.  If you manage everything properly (if any managing is even needed), it won't cause you any problems.  I'd imagine making the temp will be faster as well since you'd only be making one cast as opposed to casting EVERYTIME for EVERY member of the struct.

Answer (score 1):

The first question is why does the function take a `void*` in the first place. If that is changed to the exact type of pointer, then the problem goes away altogether.

If you are going to use the pointer (after casting to the appropriate type) more than once in the function, I would just create a local variable of the given type, cast once and then use it. As of the cost of creating such a variable, in many cases the compiler will optimize the variable away (if you doubt, look at the generated assembly).

Comment: "Why does the function take a void*?"  The application is an imbedded processor using a simple "run to completion" dispatcher.  Arbitrary messages (structures) can be passed to a task; the dispatcher casts the pointer to the message to a void*, otherwise I would have to use something like a switch statement in the dispatcher to make the call with the correct pointer type (kinda ugly).

Comment: I thought it might be something like that.  One other way to handle that would be for all of your messages to be classes that inherit the same parent.  (That assumes your dispatcher is in C++.)

Answer (score 0):

> but it seems like it shouldn't be necessary to create a temporary variable just for this purpose

Um, it's not: like you said, you can do a cast in-place.

Make your choice: cast every time (messy) or cast once into a variable of the correct type (clean).

Answer (score 0):

Change the type of `pMsg` to `struct MyEventMsg *` and create a second, inline version of the method that takes a `void *`, casts it and calls the first one.

You can prevent calls to the first method by making it private.